# How to connect all related DB with FK in Django?

Tags: mysql, django

I got problem in making Queries. In the shell I all the time faced 'user' has no split error. and want to know how to make query about those models.

```
select i.id, i.name, i.email, i.memo, g.id, g.name, i.birthday, i.regdt, n.number, t.name, t.id
  from webcontact_info as i
 inner join webcontact_number as n on i.id = n.info_id
 inner join webcontact_group as g on i.group_id = g.id
 inner join webcontact_type as t on n.type_id = t.id;
```

this query in mysql. how can i change into query for Django?
please help me about this.

those are models.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Type(models.Model) :
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Info(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
        memo = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        birthday = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=True, blank=True)
        group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        regdt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updatedt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Number(models.Model):
        number = models.CharField(max_length=11)
        info = models.ForeignKey(Info, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        regdt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updatedt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use your related object with your object. But maybe you're looking for `select_related`.

It will return selecting additional related-object data - It will boost query performance bit much.

`infos = Info.objects.select_related('user', 'group', 'user__number')`.

Check more detail in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: type name and group name all will be in object infos?

Comment: What do you mean add type name? Want to get name form type object?

Comment: I mean not type name. group and Info two tables are not in relation with FK. right?
but you mean type table records are including in 'infos'?

Comment: your `Info` model has `group` fields related with `Group`. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry my question was wrong. I'm in work that's why I made a mistake to ask you.
I mean Info model doesn't have any relations with Type model. Number model has  FK with Type.

Comment: @Sugarpresso you can access your type and group name by dots. `infos.group.name`.

Comment: @JonhyBeebop and also I can use like abc=infos.filter(info_id=1) to find each user information. right?

Comment: @Sugarpresso You always can get related object with django queryset. `selected_related` is for optimizing queryset. btw, you can get like `abc=infos.filter(id=1)` cause it's `Info` model's queryset.

Comment: @Sugarpresso yep. But try to filter it once in select_related. `infos = Info.objects.select_related('user', 'group', 'user__number').filter(info__id=1)`. Because filter hits your database.

Comment: @JonhyBeebop Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @seuling Thank you so much for it! I just get started to learn right now. lol