# How can I deal with filter object in HTML

Tags: django, html

[image]

I tried with above to see how I can use with objects in showing in homepage.

few people recommend me to use this code below

```
infos = Info.objects.select_related('user','group', 'user_number').filter(id = newc.id)
```

and my model code is like this.

```
class Group(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Type(models.Model) :
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Info(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
        memo = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        birthday = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=True, blank=True)
        group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        regdt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updatedt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Number(models.Model):
        number = models.CharField(max_length=11)
        info = models.ForeignKey(Info, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        regdt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updatedt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and in my views.py.

```
def addcontract(request) :
        if request.user.is_authenticated :
                pk = request.user.id
                name = request.POST['name']
                email = request.POST['email']
                memo = request.POST['memo']
                birthday = request.POST['birthday']
                group_id = request.POST['group_id']
                type_id = request.POST['type_id']
                number = request.POST['number']
                user_id = pk
                newc = Info(
                        name = name, email = email, memo = memo, birthday = birthday,
                        group_id = group_id, user_id = pk)
                newc.save()
                number = Number(number = number, type_id= type_id, user_id = pk, info = newc)
                number.save()
                infos = Info.objects.select_related('user','group', 'user_number').filter(id = newc.id)
                grouplist = Group.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id)
                typelist = Type.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id)
                return render(request, 'detail.html',
                        {'infos':infos, 'grouplist':grouplist, 'typelist':typelist})
```

My previous question was

[How to connect all related DB with FK in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374170/how-to-connect-all-related-db-with-fk-in-django)

it doesn't work in homepage at all to show from object that's why I tried to check in homepage then problem occured.

user_id is only for account. I need to use Info_id as a fk all in query
please help this.

Comment: No `user__number` with *two* underscores. But this will not work anyway, since it is a *one-to-many* relation. So you should use `prefetch_related`.

Comment: Furthermore if you look back to the answer, you see that it is `.filter(info__id=1)`. Did you actually understand the answer that seuling has written?

Comment: z=Info.objects.select_related('user','group','user__username').get(id = 1) z.user.username

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hey. Thanks for answering this. yes I tried before all two underscore and filter with info two underscore. and when I have done those advices. It hasn't been worked so.. I tried one underscore.

and when I tried with info__id being error for 'Cannot resolve keyword 'info' into field'